# Do we need to know about the database schema for designing Rest API?

Tags: rest, api, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have to develop an android application where I may not be provided with the database schema for security purposes. The way they are suggesting is to use Restful API as an interface between the application and the database. Is it possible to design Restful API without knowing anything about the database schema?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to develop a RESTful API without knowing anything about the database at all.

They will need to give you the endpoints/URL's for the web service and generally there will also be documentation describing the format and structure of the response you can expect when calling the web services. Optionally they will also specify if the request needs to contain any parameters and how it should be structured as well as how to authenticate if required to.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial links to get started?. Thank you in advance